# Declare an array in the private section of a class and assign the Array values in the Constructor

Tags: c++

I'm trying to declare an array property and then initialize the array in the constructor but I am getting error: Expected expression.

```
class LargestArray
{
  private:
    int array[5];
    int size;`
  public:
    LargestArray()
    {
      array[]  = { 18, 38, 24, 57, 69 };
      size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    }
    void largest();
    void secondLargest();
    void kLargest();
    void threeLargest();
 };
```

can somebody help me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not assignable. Also, `array[]  = {...}` is not syntactically meaningful.

Array members, like all members, are initialised with a member initialiser:

```
LargestArray(): array{ 18, 38, 24, 57, 69 }
{
  ...
```

There is no need for a non-static member `size`, because the size of the array cannot change at runtime.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not syntactically meaningful'?  What is wrong with this code?
class LargestArray
{
  private:
    int array[5] { 18, 38, 24, 57, 69 };
.....

Comment: @shargors it means that the c++ language has no such syntax. It is a syntax error. What you've written is different, and there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Got you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**You can initialize the array in the constructor member initializer list**

```
A::A() : array{2,3,4,1,6,5,4} {

}
```

or for older syntax

```
A::A() : array({2,3,4,1,6,5,4}) {

}
```

Your sample should compile, using a compiler supporting the latest standard though.